# How to get raw representation of existing string or escaping backslash

Tags: python, string

***Problem***

I'm running dataflow job where I have steps - reading txt file from cloud storage using dataflow/beam - [apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.5.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText) which has StrUtf8Coder (utf-8) by default and after that loading it into postgres using StringIteratorIO with copy_from.

data coming from pcollection element by element, there are some elements which will look like this:

```py
line = "some information|more information S\\\\H,  F\226|DIST|local|app\\\\\lock\|"
```

After that, I need to download it to postgres (the delimiter here is "|"), but the problem is these kinds of elements because postgres try to encode it(and I'm getting: *'invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"'*):

from **F\226** we are getting this -> **F\x96**

This slash is *not visible* so **I can not** just replace it like this:

```py
line.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

Using python 3.8.

Have tried repr() or encode("unicode_escape").decode()

Also in every line we have different elements so let's say in the next one can be **r\456**

I'm able to catch and change it with regex only if I will use a raw string, but not sure how to represent a regular string as a raw if we already have it in a variable.

```py
import re

line = r"some information|more information S\\\\H,  F\226|DIST|local|app\\\\\lock\|"
updated = re.sub("([a-zA-Z])\\\\(\\d*)", "\\1\\\\\\\\\\2",string)
print(updated)

$  some information|more information S\\\\\H,  F\\226|DIST|local|app\\\\\\lock\\|
```

***Goal***

Have an extra backslash if after backslash we have some element, so the line need to look like this:

```py
line = "some information|more information S\\\\\H,  F\\226|DIST|local|app\\\\\\lock\\|"
```

Thank's for any help!

Comment: `\226` is the same as `\x96`, just using different escaping variant. But indeed, this byte is not valid in UTF-8, what character did the *file.txt* actually mean, what encoding does the file use?

Comment: If your goal really is to get the escape sequence for that byte, instead of the character, then `repr()` should have worked.

Comment: @Bergi it is just some data that is written in this manner it is not some kind of encoding, I need to have this line in exact same look as I get

Comment: You say you're reading from some file, but haven't shown the code that you use for reading nor the contents of the file. The string representation of the line is not really relevant, it doesn't matter what it "looks like". It definitely is an encoding issue.

Comment: @Bergi I'm reading txt file from cloud storage using dataflow/beam - apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText() which has StrUtf8Coder (utf-8) by default

Comment: Are you sure that the file that you're reading from the cloud storage actually is encoded using utf-8?

Comment: @Bergi yes I'm sure. The actual problem was in StringIteratorIO which I'm using in copy_from - it was actually losing backslashes while reading from the buffer line by line. But thank you anyway - because of you I check all encoding/decoding places in my code and now have a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to read the file in binary or select the encoding, you could get a better starting point. This is how to do it in binary:

```
>>> line = b"some information|more information S\\\\H,  F\226|DIST|local|app\\\\\lock\|"
>>> line.decode('cp1252')
'some information|more information S\\\\H,  F–|DIST|local|app\\\\\\lock\\|'
```

This is how to decode the whole file:

```
f = open('file.txt', encoding='cp1252')
f.read()
```

The encoding CP-1252 is the [legacy Microsoft latin-1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: This is the correct solution (though maybe not the correct encoding). @Roma you do *not* want to "add an extra backslash", i.e. escape the byte.